# Почему консоль выдает ошибку в callback ф-ии?

Tags: javascript

Почему консоль выдает ошибку **Uncaught ReferenceError: arr is not defined**?

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
let out1 = document.querySelector('.out-1');
let out2 = document.querySelector('.out-2');
let out3 = document.querySelector('.out-3');

function f1(myFunc) {
   myFunc(arr, block);
}

function showArr(arr, block) {
   arr[3] = arr[3] * 10;
   block.innerHTML = arr.join('_');
}

f1(showArr(arr1, out1))
```

```html
<div class="out-1"></div>
<div class="out-2"></div>
<div class="out-3"></div>
```

А при таком написании не выдает ошибку, НО при выводе в блок out2 почему третий элемент массива сохраняет условия и остается 40, хотя в условии я поставил задачу только для четвертого элемента массива?

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
let out1 = document.querySelector('.out-1');
let out2 = document.querySelector('.out-2');
let out3 = document.querySelector('.out-3');

function f1(myFunc, arr, block) {
   myFunc(arr, block);
}

function showArr(arr, block) {
   arr[3] = arr[3] * 10;
   block.innerHTML = arr.join('_');
}

function showArr2(arr, block) {
   arr[4] = arr[4] * 100;
   block.innerHTML = arr.join(' ');
}

f1(showArr, arr1, out1);
f1(showArr2, arr1, out2);
```

```html
<div class="out-1"></div>
<div class="out-2"></div>
<div class="out-3"></div>
```

Comment: У вас тут комплекс ) По первому - в функции `f1` переменная не определена, вот и ошибка об этом говорит. Во втором случае - вы передаете ссылку на массив, и каждая функция мутирует данный объект. Первый вызов функции меняет значение массива и далее измененный массив меняется при втором вызове. Почитайте про [массивы](https://learn.javascript.ru/array) и [объекты](https://learn.javascript.ru/object)

Comment: Много времени на сокращении "ф-ии" сэкономил?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема тут:

> ```
> function f1(myFunc) {
>    myFunc(arr, block);
> }
> ```

Вы передаете в функцию f1 не другую функцию, а возвращаемое ею значение:

> ```
> f1(showArr(arr1, out1))
> ```

Из-за этого во-первых myFunc не является функцией, во вторых вы отправляете в *myFunc* массив *arr* и элемент *block*, которые не объявлены, отсюда и ошибка.

---

Исправить можно так:

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
let out1 = document.querySelector('.out-1');
let out2 = document.querySelector('.out-2');
let out3 = document.querySelector('.out-3');

function f1(myFunc) {
   myFunc(arr1, out1);
}

function showArr(arr, block) {
   arr[3] = arr[3] * 10;
   block.innerHTML = arr.join('_');
}

f1(showArr)
```

```html
<div class="out-1"></div>
<div class="out-2"></div>
<div class="out-3"></div>
```